# Update folder name using REST API

Tags: 2013, rest, client-object-model, folder

I am using REST to update folder name via sharepoint apps. My code as follows:

```
executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
executor.executeAsync({
        url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + libraryToSearch + "/" + oldFolderName +"')?@target='" + mysiteUrl + "'";
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            "IF-MATCH":"*"
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: '{ "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Folder" }, "Name": "Test Update" }',        
        success: FolderNameUpdateSuccess,
        error: FolderNameUpdateFailure
    });
```

Finally it is coming to the success block, but folder name is not updating... I searched for long time but no result. What could be the problem here? In success block data is retreiving like below. 
[image]

`Status Text` comes out as "No Content", what does it mean?

Comment: What's the value of `libraryToSearch`? Does it include the initial slash (/)?  Server relative url's begin with a slash.  If the url is as follows: `Documents/MyFolderToRename`, it will fail.  However, `/Documents/MyFolderToRename` will not.

Comment: That url is correct becuase it i am using same format for another operations like get, delete. However format is `Documents/MyFolderToRename`

Comment: When I try to update the `welcomepage` for a folder it is updating but only for `Name` it is not working? What could be the reason?

Comment: Hmm, how misleading, did not know site relative url's were valid (no leading slash means site relative).  This is a stab in the dark, but try adding `/ListItemAllFields` to the end, and changing `Title`.

Comment: You mean to say, I have to add like `/Documents/MyFolderToRename` ?

Comment: No, the way you had it before works.  I was just commenting on the difference between having the preceding slash and not.  Try adding `/ListItemAllFields` to the end of your REST url (before the query string portion).  This points to the item's fields, rather than the folder.  Maybe changing the `Title` field here will change the name.  Like I mentioned before, this is a guess.

Comment: I tried all the possibilities. It is updating "welcomepage" property for a folder but not "Name" i don't know why this weird behavior. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15471/discussion-between-wjervis-and-mihir).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SP.Folder.name property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246939(v=office.15).aspx) is *read-only* and hence it could not be used in update operation.

### How to rename Folder using SharePoint 2013 REST

The following example demonstrates how to rename Folder using SharePoint 2013 REST API:

```
function executeJson(url,method,additionalHeaders,payload) 
{
    var headers = {};
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }   
    if (typeof additionalHeaders != 'undefined') {
        for(var key in additionalHeaders){
            headers[key] = additionalHeaders[key];
        }    
    }    

    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if(method == "POST") {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(payload);
    }  

    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}

function renameFolder(webUrl,folderUrl,name)
{
     var folderItemUrl =  webUrl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + folderUrl + "')/ListItemAllFields";
     return executeJson(folderItemUrl,"GET").then(
         function(data){         
             var itemPayload = {};
             itemPayload['__metadata'] = {'type': data.d['__metadata']['type']};
             itemPayload['Title'] = name;
             itemPayload['FileLeafRef'] = name;
             var itemUrl = data.d['__metadata']['uri'];
             var additionalHeaders = {};
             additionalHeaders["X-HTTP-Method"] = "MERGE";
             additionalHeaders["If-Match"] =  "*";
             return executeJson(itemUrl,"POST",additionalHeaders,itemPayload);
         });
}
```

**Usage**

How to rename folder named `2014` located under `Documents` library to `Archive`:

```
renameFolder(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'/Shared Documents/2014','Archive')
.done(function()
{
    console.log('Folder has been renamed');
})
.fail(
function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

**Update**

How to rename Folder using SharePoint 2013 REST (ver 2)

```
function renameFolder(webUrl,listTitle,itemId,name)
{
     var itemUrl =  webUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/Items(" + itemId + ")";
     var itemPayload = {};
     itemPayload['__metadata'] = {'type': getItemTypeForListName(listTitle)};
     itemPayload['Title'] = name;
     itemPayload['FileLeafRef'] = name;
     var additionalHeaders = {};
     additionalHeaders["X-HTTP-Method"] = "MERGE";
     additionalHeaders["If-Match"] =  "*";
     return executeJson(itemUrl,"POST",additionalHeaders,itemPayload);
}


function getItemTypeForListName(name) {
   return"SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1) + "ListItem";
}
```

Comment: Thanks and I will try your solution. But why microsoft is giving the supported method as like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553(v=office.15).aspx#Folders ?

Comment: You could even use this approach if Folder contains files ;)

Comment: I have one doubt. When these `then` and `done` functions should be use? Can be use without `deferred` object? Because I didn't saw any deferred object reference with your example.

Comment: The purpose of usage deferred.then() since in my example  2 requests are called: 1) get ListItem associated with Folder resource using /_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(serverrelativeurl)/ and 2)update ListItem resource.  But it could be performed using a single REST request as demonstrated in the updated answer.

Comment: Okay.. do you know how to clear the cache for the deferred object. For two requests I am getting the same response.