# Rename folder with SharePoint online REST API 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, rest, folder, update

I want to rename folder via SharePoint Online REST API from CRM Plugin. Below is my code. I am getting `HTTP 204` response, but the folder name is not changed.

Please can someone tell what is wrong with code?

I am using `[SharepointSiteUrl]/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('[oldFolderPath]')/ListItemAllFields`

---

```
string folderUrl = SharepointUtility.GetFolderUpdateUrl(this.pluginConfiguration, oldFolderPath);

HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(folderUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

request.Method = "POST";
request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
request.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose";
request.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", digestValue);
request.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f"); 
request.Headers["X-HTTP-Method"] = "PATCH";
request.Headers["IF-MATCH"] = "*";
request.CookieContainer = authorizationCookie;

// Setting change folder data
string requestData = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'Name': '" + newFolderName + "' }";
request.ContentLength = requestData.Length;

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write(requestData);
writer.Flush();
writer.Close();

using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string responseString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105408/update-folder-name-using-rest-api

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does not work for me, because I need to do this from the C# code in the CRM ONLINE plugin. But I have set the request like in this post, and get the HTTP 204 response with no folder name change

Answer (score 2):

The endpoint you are using cannot be used to change the Name of the folder because the Name property is not editable.

1. Make a **GET** request to get the **item id**/**URI** and the **type** of the folder.

**ENDPOINT URI:** `<SiteURL>/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('<FoldFolderPath>')/ListItemAllFields`

2. From the response of the above request, extract **uri** attribute value and **type** attribute value.
3. Make another POST request with ENDPOINT as the **uri** extracted from the above step.

**ENDPOINT URI** format will be like: `<SharepointSiteUrl>/_api/Web/Lists(guid'<Guid if list>')/Items(<id of item>)`

**Note:** If you know the ID of the folder item, you can skip step 1.

Answer (score 1):

Each folder has a list item associated with it. The way you change the name of the folder is by changing the Title *and* FileLeafRef field values of the associated list item (obvious - right)?

If you take a look at the code in the answer linked in Unnie's comment you can see that is what the author is doing.

[image: Code snip]