# Can we rename a document set using REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-set

I have created an document set with a temporary name but now want to rename it using REST API.

I do not want to create a new document set and move the files to the new location.

Is there any way to accomplish my requirement?

Comment: try this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105408/update-folder-name-using-rest-api

Comment: this thread will be useful as well [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114882/is-it-possible-to-create-a-document-set-using-rest-api)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a Document Set is basically a folder. Here's an example for "Shared Documents" and a folder or doc set named "Toys".

URL:

```
https://yourServer/sites/training/demoworkflow/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents/Toys')/ListItemAllFields
```

Method:

```
POST
```

Headers:

```
{ "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
    "If-Match":  "*",
    "content-length":___yourBodyLen___,
    "X-RequestDigest": "___yourRequestDigest___"}
```

Body:

```
{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.Shared_x0020_DocumentsItem"},
               "Title":"TestToysDocs", "FileLeafRef":"TestToysDocs" }
```

Replace the `___text___` with your data.