# Invalid request while renaming sub folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, ajax

When I'm trying to rename sub floder, I'm getting issue mention below:

> "{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Invalid request."}}}"

Code:

```
var itemPayload = {};
itemPayload['Title'] = "new name";
itemPayload['FileLeafRef'] = "new name";

var headers = {};
headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: spURL + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/a/b/c')/ListItemAllFields",
    data: JSON.stringify(itemPayload),
    headers: headers,
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Refer this link - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105408/update-folder-name-using-rest-api

Answer (score 0):

answer:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(UpdateListItem, "sp.js");

function UpdateListItem(){
    var clientContext;
    var oWebsite;
    var oList;

    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("DocumentLibrary");

    oListItem = oList.getItemById(1);

    this.oListItem.set_item("FileLeafRef", "Folder Name");

    this.oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(this.oListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFailure);
}
function onSuccess() {
        alert('Update succeeded.');
}
function onFailure(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Thanks